# Why am I getting an IndexError from a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.7

I'm writing code that will take dates and numeric values from a csv file and compare them.

```py
date_location = 3
numeric_location = 4

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f1:
    next(f1)
    with open('file2.csv', 'r') as f2:
        next(f2)
        for i in (f1):
            f1_date = (i.split()[date_location])
            f1_number = (i.split()[numeric_location])
            for j in (f2):
                f2_date = (j.split()[date_location])
                f2_number = (j.split()[numeric_location])
                print(f1_date, f1_number)
                print(f2_date, f2_number)
                if f1_date == f2_date:
                    print(f1_date == f2_date)
                    if f2_number > f1_number:
                        print('WIN')
                        continue
                    elif f2_number <= f1_number:
                        print('lose')
               f2.seek(0, 0)`
```

I get this error `IndexError: list index out of range` for `f1_date = (i.split()[date_location])`, which i assume will also affect:

`f1_number = (i.split()[numeric_location])`

`f2_date = (j.split()[date_location])`

`f2_number = (j.split()[numeric_location])`

Can anyone explain why? I haven't found a way to make it so this error doesn't show.

EDIT: I forgot to change the separator for `.split()` after messing around with the for loop using text files

Comment: It would help to know what is in the files being read.

Comment: in both files there are basic stock market data, so, ticker symbols, dates, open, close, high, and low values

Comment: If it’s a csv file, then surely you should be using `split(',')` ... but even better would be to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

Comment: add `print(i.split())` and `print(date_location)` before that line and find out why it goes wrong...

Comment: As an aside, you are iterating multiple times over the same file handle, so the iterator will be exhausted after the first loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes, that's why I included `f2.seek(0, 0)` so that it will keep iterating until the first file is exhausted

Comment: Ah, missed that.

Comment: I noticed that even though the fields in your files are separated by *commas* (since you're using CSV files), you split each line in your file with the `split()` method -- which splits on whitespace by default. I have a hunch that when you try to split `i`, you get a list with too few fields because you are splitting on the wrong delimiter, which would lead to your `IndexError`.

Comment: @jjramsey That's what seems to be the case, as I forgot to include the proper delimiter to `i.split()` and `j.split()`

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about debugging your code.

Comment: Also take a look at the `csv` package in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main possibilities:

**1)** Your csv files are not space delimited, and as the default separator for `.split()` is `" "`, you will not have at least 4 space-separated items in `i.split()` (or 5 for `numeric_location`).

**2)** Your csv is space delimited, but is ragged, i.e. it has incomplete rows, so for some row, there is no data for column 4.

I also highly suggest using a library for reading csvs. `csv` is in the standard library, and `pandas` has built-in handling of ragged lines.

Comment: I ended up forgetting to include the proper separator for `.split()`, Thank you!
Also, these two files have already been modified with pandas and I would much rather prefer to continue using pandas the whole way through, but I just couldn't find a way to compare the two like I have here using pandas,

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you only have one element in the case of `i.split()`
 But `date_location` is equal to 3.

You need to add a separator based on your csv file in the str.split method.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Or maybe 2 or 3 elements. The OP is trying to use indexes 3 and 4.

Comment: Umm I doubt it as he didn't add any delimiter while reading the file !

Comment: I forgot to add the delimiter to `i.split()`

Answer (score 0):

```
f1_number = (i.split()[numeric_location])
```

This is doing a lot in a single line. I suggest you split this into two lines:

```
f1 = i.split()
f1_number = f1[numeric_location]
f1_date = f1[date_location]
```

Now you will see which of these causes the problem. You should add a `print(f1)` to see the value after the split. Most likely it doesn't have as many elements as you think it does. Or your indexes are off from what they should be.

Comment: Thank you, but I was messing around with the for loop using a `.txt` file and forgot to include the delimiter for `i.split()` when I changed it to open a csv file

Comment: @user63266 Glad you figured it out. What I wrote here can help you work through your code to find such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The call to i.split() is going to generate a new list, which will contain each word of the from the string i. So

```
"this is an example".split() == ["this", "is", "an", "example"]
```

You are trying to access the third element of the resulting list, and the index error tells you that this list has less than four members. I suggest printing the result of i.split(). Very likely this is either an off by one error, or the first line of your file contains something different than what you are expecting.

Also split() by default will split on whitespace, given that you have a csv you may have wanted to do split(',').

Comment: Thank you, this is what ended up happening as I forgot to include the delimiter on the call to `i.split()` since I was messing around with the for loop with text files